# How can i export data in CSV to be used in PHP from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have mysql table where i have column `content` which is email replies in text format.

Now i want to export into CSV to be used in my PHP program.

Currently i have exported using `mysql -B` and my result in text looks like

```
uid eid content
266466  30311650    can i reply plz
\n
\nthanks,
\n
\nPaul
\n
\n
\nOn Wed, Dec 18, 2013 at 2:41 PM, 
\n
\n> contest "dfhfd".
\n>
\n>
\n
266466  30312072    john reply to mike
\n
\nholla yeah <b>bold me</b>
\n
\n
\nOn Wed, Dec 18, 2013 at 3:57 PM, 
\n>
\n>
\n
```

Now i want to read in PHP as separate rows but i don't know how can i separate the records currently the records are tab separated but i think there can be many tabs inside email as well.

Even i am not able to read this file in MS Excel as well

Comment: Your CSV is far from following the [format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180#section-2).

Comment: Why do you go a long way round a csv export? Can't you connect to the database?

Comment: @VMai actually that table is very big around 30GB and i only have selected records like 4000 on which i want to test. i thought to put in csv and then try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `mysql -B`

```
SELECT uid,eid,content
  FROM myTable
  INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/file.csv'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      ENCLOSED BY '"'
         LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

This will only generate the output on the MySQL server filesystem, if you don't have access to that server, then you can achieve the same result using:

```
mysql -u user -h host -ppassword -ss \
    -e "SELECT uid,eid,content FROM myTable" mydatabase \
    | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' > myOutputFile.csv
```

while will generate a file on the server where you're executing the command

Comment: i cant access the mysql directly so i can't get the file , is there any way to execute this command using `mysql -t` so that i get the file in my server not on mysql server

Comment: wont it replace the tabs which are inside the message

Answer (score 0):

**this is how i use mysql to get CSV export.**
hope this will help you

```
$rows= mysql_query("SELECT email_id FROM table") or die mysql_error();

$headers= array('Email Id');

if ($fp && $rows) {

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

    fputcsv($fp, $headers);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)){        

  fputcsv($fp, array_values(array(''.$row['email_id'].'')));

  }
 readfile($filename);       
 die;
}
```